# fill missing days in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, missing-data

Given the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1,3],[1,2,6],[1,4,3],[2,2,6]],columns=['ID','Day','Value'])

df
Out[58]: 
   ID  Day  Value
0   1    1      3
1   1    2      6
2   1    4      3
3   2    2      6
```

As you can see for ID = 1 the Value related to Day3 is missing and for ID =2 the value related to Day1 is missing... I would like to fill these gaps adding np.nan and the missing day...

```
Out[59]: 
   ID  Day  Value
0   1    1    3.0
1   1    2    6.0
2   1    3    NaN
3   1    4    3.0
4   2    1    NaN
5   2    2    6.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to define a custom function that performs some reindexing logic:

```
def f(x):
    return x.set_index('Day').reindex(
               np.arange(1, x.Day.max() + 1)
          ).Value
```

Now, perform a `groupby` + `apply`:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(f).reset_index()

   ID  Day  Value
0   1    1    3.0
1   1    2    6.0
2   1    3    NaN
3   1    4    3.0
4   2    1    NaN
5   2    2    6.0
```

Comment: Props for understanding the question.  I wasn't sure what data OP thought he was missing until I read this answer.